# Elliptic regularity on the cube

Tags: regularity-theory-of-pdes, elliptic-equations

Does anyone know if elliptic regularity still holds in the d-dimensional cube $Q:=[0,1]^d$ with Neumann boundary conditions ? More precisely, let $\rho\in C^{0,\alpha}(Q)$ (let say scalar) with $\alpha\in (0,1)$ and consider the $H^1(Q)$-solution $f$ of
$$
\left\{
    \begin{array}{ll}
        -\nabla\cdot \rho\nabla f=g  & \text{in $Q$} \\
        \partial_n f\equiv 0 & \mbox{on $\partial Q$},
    \end{array}
\right.
$$
where $\partial_n$ denotes the normal derivative and $g\in L^{\infty}(Q)$. Do I have for $\alpha'<\alpha$
$$\|\nabla f\|_{C^{0,\alpha'}(Q)}\leq C \|g\|_{L^{\infty}(Q)},$$
for a constant $C$ depending of $\|\rho\|_{C^{0,\alpha}(Q)}$ ? If yes, does anyone have a reference for that ?

Thank you !

Comment: Yeah, I don't know, but I played with this toy model. Take $Q=[0, 2\pi]\times [0, 2\pi]$ and $\rho=1$. So you have $-\Delta f=g$. For example, $f(x, y)=\cos(n x)\cos(ny)$ is an eigenfunction of $-\Delta$. Then you are asking for $\nabla f$ to be bounded by $n^2$, which indeed seems to be the case

Comment: Hi ! Thank you for this example ! I think for the Laplacian case, it is true since by Fourier transform one can for instance explicitly write the Green's function and then express the solution explicitly. It is quite direct to see that the Green's function enjoys classical bounds which allow to prove the regularity estimate. But I don't know any reference for the Green's function for non-homogeneous operators in the cube...

Comment: And what is the Green function in the case of $\rho=1$? I'm curious.